# Argument type inference not working as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have the following:

```
declare function foo<T>(arg: T[]): void;
foo([1, "a", new Date()]); // Ok, inferred as foo<number|string|Date>(...)
```

The above case works fine, but here is the problem:

```
type I<T> = { x: T };
declare function foo<T>(arg: I<T>[]): void;
foo([{x: 1}, {x: "a"}]); // Error, type string is not assignable to type number
```

In the above case the function type is inferred as `foo<number>(...)`.

Is there any way to modify declaration of I or foo() to make the inference work, meaning to get inferred type as `foo<number|string>`?

I also noticed that the this works:

```
foo<number|string>([{x: 1}, {x: "a"}]);
```

but how to make it work without explicitly providing type parameters?

Also, even this doesn't seem to work:

```
type I<T> = { x: T };
declare function foo<T>(arg: I<T>[]): T;
const res: number|string = foo([{x: 1}, {x: "a"}]); // Still same error
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgPAFQHxQLxQN5QB4C4oJQC+A3AFBkAmEAxgDYCGATtAGYCuAdjcAJYD2nKK378ATIigRswCJ0oBnWHC4BrTvwDunJAG0AukgAUzAOb4EASgu7O7ALYAjCE326A5Nnf7yNQQuAoFgUxfDsnFygAHygApl5OUzRhUTEjXSw8KABGYgAaTBx8dwZ3Yn1LciA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the type parameter definition to be the whole thing, to make API clear i have to keep the original meaning of T.

Comment: Okay, but can you change `T` to `I<unknown>` like in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgPAFQHxQLxQN5QB4C4oJQC+A3AFBkAmEAxgDYCGATtAGYCuAdjcAJYD2nKK378ATIigRswCJ0oBnWHC4BrTvwDunJEgAUzAOb4EAbQC6AShOmA5NlvmyNQQuBQWCsWmGixe0yw8KABGYgAaTBx8WwZbCMxg4CZ2CCIrciA)?

Comment: Thanks, this is actually better, unfortunately it still changes the definition of `T`, which will make it harder to call when user wants to provide type parameter explicitly.  I m wondering if it's possible to keep the original meaning of `T` but change the definition of `I` somehow.  Maybe what i m asking could be impossible of course.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible using [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in typescript. The problem here its that you does not have a homogeneous array(some cases it can be a anti-pattern), so you need to iterate in each item type to discover generic type, so your code will look like this:

```
type I<T> = { x: T };
type Is<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: I<T[Key]>
}

declare function foo2<T>(arg: Is<T>): void;
const res2 = foo2([{ x: 1 }, { x: 'a' }]);
```

i added a [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgPAFQHxQLxQN5QB4C4oJQC%20A3AFCiSwDOiK6GZUzUA2gNIQhQCWAdlADWXAPYAzAgF188BBy6SkZImTIATCAGMANgEMATtDEBXPpuA8RAsSJEAmRFAjZgEPmupQAgvv26QcKaCfCIA7nxISAAUBgDmMrTIAJT4cnzGALYARhD6kuSaVtTAUIbUdmhQNvZRrFh4UACMxAA0mDj4AOS6ncSSSeRAA)

Comment: I m not very clear how type `Is[T]` is equivalent to `I<T>[]`? If i do e.g. `keyof number` it just shows me the methods of the Number class.

Comment: If I modify your definition to be an array-like: `[Key in keyof T[]]: I<T>`, but then i get the original error.

Comment: hi, sorry i does not understand what you mean, would you put your doubt in ts playground, so i can help you

Comment: Can you please explain how the type `Is<T>` works?